# bootstrap navbar doesnt work as I intended it to do

Tags: html, css, vue.js, jquery-ui, bootstrap-5

So I created a landing page with a bootstrap navbar but whenever I decrease the size of the screen the hamburger doesnt show the list of items I have in it which is what I was trying to do here is my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" id="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="header">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center ml-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="../assets/img/dreamers logo.png" width="80px;" class="mr-2">
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Booking App</a>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="sideheader" style="padding-right: 40px;">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ml-4">
      <li class="nav-item ms-2">
        <a class="nav-link" id="home1" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ms-2">
        <a class="nav-link" id="home1" href="#feature">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ms-2">
        <a class="nav-link" id="about1" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="btn btn-custom-btn ms-2" @click="openLoginModal" style="color: black;">Login</button>
    <button class="btn btn-custom-btn ms-4" @click="openRegisterModal" style="color: black;">Register</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is not the full code just a snippet of it

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue, not *just a snippet of it*.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have included the Bootstrap CSS file and the required JavaScript files in your HTML code. You can include them by adding the following lines inside the  section of your HTML file:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already have that in my index.html apparently and I also installed it locally but still btw Im using vue js